# Cannot Update AMD Radeon Settings (No Error Given)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, amd-radeon

I am running Windows 10 Pro and am using [this video card](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814131672).

Recently (within the past few weeks), Windows has been letting me know that there are updates available to the driver software in AMD Radeon Settings. So far so good:

[image: AMD Radeon Settings Prompt]

I click the "New Recommended" box, and select Custom Upgrade. (This scenario also occurs if I click Express Upgrade). It prompts me to confirm:

[image: AMD Radeon Settings Confirm Upgrade Prompt]

After I confirm, it puts up a loading indicator as if it's starting something up:

[image: AMD Radeon Settings Thinking]

But after that it just returns to the first image, as if I'd never clicked anything.

- AMD Radeon Settings is never "exited" despite the prompt's claim that it'll do so.
- No other programs or installers start up (not even a flicker on the taskbar, i.e. nothing immediately starting/stopping) or anything.
- No errors or messages are given at all.

I've tried running AMD Radeon Settings as Administrator, but that didn't cut it either. Has anyone run into this before? It's not absolutely critical that I upgrade immediately or anything, but I would like to have the matter resolved so that I can upgrade (and so I can stop that pop-up from reminding me there's updates every time).

Comment: Go to the AMD website, download the installation manually, run installation manually.  If that still doesn't work, remove your current AMD installation then install the current AMD installation

Comment: @Ramhound I grabbed the version matching the same number in the screenshot from [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-Crimson-ReLive-Edition-17.2.1-Release-Notes.aspx). This seemed to work. However, I'm still wondering why the built-in updater didn't work in the first place.

Comment: Let's go with an application bug.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [Controlled Folder Access](https://www.howto-connect.com/enable-controlled-folder-access-windows-10/) enabled?  If so, add `C:\Program Files\AMD\CNext\CNext\RadeonSettings.exe` as an allowed app.

I have this Windows feature enabled as it can help protect from ransomware and other malware, but I do have problems with apps throwing error tantrums a lot. This is usually the first thing I check was an app gives appropriate error messages add the .exe as an allowed app.  Since there was no error message from Radeon Settings, I assumed it was a bug with the program.  But when I eventually added RadeonSettings.exe as an allowed app, the installer ran!